# how to delete eventListener. removeEventListener doesn't work

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a button 'Start Game', when you click on which the game starts and the word on the button changes to "Repeat" - a random card is selected and the sound of the word of the card is played and you need to guess which card it is. But when the game has started, if you press this button, then it should already work as a repeater, i.e. so that you can listen to the word again. How to delete the playback of a new word when you press the button, and to repeat the already voiced one. RemoveEventListener doesn't work. when i click it plays old and new word at the same time

```
const startGameBtn = document.getElementById('start-game');
startGameBtn.addEventListener('click', function() { 
  startGameBtn.innerHTML = 'Repeat';
  startGameBtn.classList.add('repeat');  
  startGame(); 
}) 
startGameBtn.removeEventListener('click', function() {
  startGame()
});
function startGame() {
  let randomCard = createRandomCard(); 
  randomCard.querySelector('audio').play(); 
  document.getElementById('category').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if(document.body.classList.contains('game-mode')) {
      if(e.target.closest('.card-item') === randomCard) {
        e.target.closest('.card-item').classList.add('checked-card');  
        randomCard = createRandomCard();
        setTimeout(function(){ randomCard.querySelector('audio').play(); }, 2500);  
      } else {
        let error = 'audio/error.mp3';
        playAudio(error)
      }    
    }   
  }) 
  document.querySelector('#start-game').addEventListener('click', function() {
    randomCard.querySelector('audio').play();
  })
}
```

Comment: `removeEventListener` should use a reference to the same function that is used with `addEventListener`, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier but i delete the same function startGame. Or i dont understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `addEventListener` you use an anonymous function which calls your `startGame` function and set the `innerHTML` and class on the button.

The function you use in `removeEventListener` is also anonymous and therefor could not ever be the **same** function as you use in `addEventListener`. This will result in the `removeEventListener` call not removing the listener, because it simply doesn't know what to remove.

So create a reference to a (non-anonymous) function and pass that reference to both `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`.

```
const startGameBtn = document.getElementById('start-game');

// Create reference to function.
const onStartClick = () => {
  startGameBtn.innerHTML = 'Repeat';
  startGameBtn.classList.add('repeat');  
  startGame(); 
};

// Use reference in adding and removing the event listeners.
startGameBtn.addEventListener('click', onStartClick);
startGameBtn.removeEventListener('click', onStartClick);
```

As for the rest of your code, keep in mind that whenever you use `addEventListener` **inside** a function that is executed on click, then you'll add a new listener after every click. That might result in unexpected behavior.